# DAX - ALLEXCEPT vs ALL+VALUES

Tags: powerbi, dax

In this video:
https://youtu.be/teYwjHkCEm0

It is said that ALLEXCEPT is not the same as ALL and VALUES. Further he says that - for filter context having CountryRegion, it makes no difference. But if there was a filter on Continent then the both are not equivalent. What exactly is happening in case of Continent?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the only existing filter is on Customer[Continent] then the

```
ALLEXCEPT( Customer, Customer[CountryRegion] )
```

simply removes all the existing filters from the `Customers` table.

The

```
ALL( Customer ),
VALUES( Customer[CountryRegion] )
```

first saves the `VALUES( Customer[CountryRegion] )`, that are in the subset of `Customer` table resulting from the filter on Continent (that's to say the `CountryRegion`s of the currently selected `continent`s), then `ALL( Customer )` filter modifier removes the existing filter on the whole `Customer` table and after that the `VALUES( Customer[CountryRegion] )` filter that was evaluated before is applied. The result is that the `CountryRegion` is "Cross-filered" by the `Continent`.

this is also explained in this article [Using ALLEXCEPT Versus ALL and-VALUES](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-allexcept-versus-all-and-values/)

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, ALL(tbl) removes filters, while VALUES([C1]) create a table filter that retains back the values of [C1] that is why this filter exists all the time unlike ALLEXCEPT (which is basically ALL) can't produce a filter unless it exists in the filter context